# addFieldToFilter `OR` condition for customer relationship in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, model

I have a custom module to store customer relationship, with database structure like this:

```
|entity_id|first_customer|second_customer|

entity_id => the relationship id
first_customer => customer id
second_customer => customer id
```

if the customer has a relationship with another customer, each of their customer id will fill first_customer and second_customer, i want to check if the relationship already exist for given 2 customer id, for example

```
+---------+--------------+---------------+
|entity_id|first_customer|second_customer|
+---------+--------------+---------------+
|    1    |      1       |     35        |
|    2    |      3       |      1        | 
|    2    |      4       |      2        | 
|    2    |      2       |      6        | 
+---------+--------------+---------------+

public function validate($customerIdA,$customerIdB){
  $friend = $this->friendFactory->create()->getCollection()
             ->addFieldToFilter(????)->getFirstItem();
  if(!empty($friend->getId())) return true;
  else return false;
}

//the order of the parameter is not gonna be the order of the filter
$this->validate(1,35); //true
$this->validate(35,1); //true
$this->validate(1,2); //false
$this->validate(1,3); //true
$this->validate(4,2); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is not entirely correct. Our suggestion is to use this:

```
$friend = $this->friendFactory
                ->create()
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter([
                    ['attribute' => 'first_customer', 'eq' => $customerIdA],
                    ['attribute' => 'second_customer', 'eq' => $customerIdB]
                ])
        ->getFirstItem();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
$friend = $this->friendFactory->create()->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter(['first_customer', 'second_customer'],
[
   ['eq' => $customerIdA],
   ['eq' => $customerIdB]
]
)->getFirstItem();;
```